# queryPedometerData returns nil steps even if there are steps logged

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I want to retrieve steps from 1h ago. I don't need to do anything special, I just need to know how many steps a user has done since the last hour.

Even though my iPhone has some steps logged, the query to retrieve the number of steps returns "nil".

This is the code:

```
   let calendar = Calendar.current //calendar now, to be used in calculating the h in the past
let beforeDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())



let pedometer = CMPedometer() //define pedometer

    if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() == true {print("steps available")}else{print("steps not available")}

    pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: beforeDate!, to: Date(), withHandler: { (pedometerData, error) in
        if let pedData = pedometerData{
            self.dateLabel.text = "Steps:\(pedData.numberOfSteps)"
        }else {
            self.dateLabel.text = "error)"
            print(beforeDate)

        }
    })
}
```

And this is the date format that I put in the query:

> 2018-03-16 12:59:17 +0000

What is wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific about what happens when the code runs. What does `print` output? What does the `dateLabel` say?

Comment: Also please prove that you have _user authorization_. You cannot fetch pedometer data without user authorization. But you have shown no authorization code. iOS 11 gives you an `authorizationStatus` property that you can use to check that you have the needed authorization.

Comment: Hi matt, when the code runs I just see that dateLabel shows "error" which means that the pedData is nil. The print was just to see the date format. In the console I also get these 2 lines: [Generic] Error on message reply (Connection invalid) and [Pedometer] Unable to parse message when checking for availability!

Comment: In future please provide that kind of information as part of the question. You get better answers faster if you don't make us guess what's going on! Thanks.

Comment: I will. Thanks Matt!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem is that your CMPedometer object is stored only in a local variable. `pedometer.queryPedometerData` runs asynchronously, so this object needs to persist long enough to fulfill the query. But it can't do that if it is a local variable; it vanishes before the data can even be fetched. Try making `pedometer` a persistent instance property instead.

Also be aware that you don't know what queue the data will be delivered on. You need to step out to the main queue in order to talk to the interface, and you are failing to do that.

Comment: It was exactly because of that. I have defined the variable outsiode vieDidLoad and it worked. Thanks!